# ScrollView Frame Color Mixing with Random Frame at top of screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uiscrollview

I have this scrollview as shown below

[image]

However, there are two problems.

Firstly, when I scroll up the red of each item "mixes" with some random white rectangle at the top of the screen to create this

[image]

Secondly the bottom tab bar shows the same random glitch and is filled with a very light red unless you scroll to the very bottom and then it shows its true color (as shown below).

Any reason why this could be happening?

Thanks

Here is the minimal code needed to reproduce error

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandingView: View {
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    @State var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        tabViewUnique()
    }
}

struct tabViewUnique: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
        
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
        
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
            TabView() {
                temp()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "globe.americas.fill")
                    }

                Text("Tab 2")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "bag")
                            
                    }
                Text("Tab 2")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.square")
                    }
                Text("Tab 2")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                    }
            }
    }
}


func temp() -> some View {
    
    let newView = VStack {
        
        //Rectangle 12
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 40)
            .padding(.vertical, 0.0)
        
        
        
        NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0..<10) {
                        Text("Item \($0)")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 200)
                            .background(.red)
                            .padding(.bottom, 20.0)
                    }
                }
    
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .padding()
    }.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
 
    return newView

}


struct landingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandingView(viewRouter: ViewRouter(), user: User())
    }
}
```

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your first issue, but for the second you can do:

```
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
```